# Routing Error uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to learn RoR. 
MY controller is

```
class SectionController < ApplicationController
  def new
    if request.post?
      u=SectionMst.new( :section_name => params[:section_name])
      u.save
      redirect_to("/section")
    else
      render 
    end
  end

  def index
    @sections = SectionMst.all
  end

  def destroy
    u=SectionMst.destroy(params[:id])
    u.save
    redirect_to("/section")
  end

  def edit
    @user = SectionMst.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

and index.html.erb is

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_section_path(section.id), method: :edit %>
```

rake routes is

```
  section_new  POST   /section/new(.:format)      section#new
               POST   /section/:id/edit(.:format) section/:id#edit
 section_index GET    /section(.:format)          section#index
               POST   /section(.:format)          section#create
 new_section   GET    /section/new(.:format)      section#new
 edit_section  GET    /section/:id/edit(.:format) section#edit
      section  GET    /section/:id(.:format)      section#show
               PUT    /section/:id(.:format)      section#update
               DELETE /section/:id(.:format)      section#destroy
```

routes.rb is

```
post "section/new"
post "section/:id/edit"
resources :section
```

i am getting the 
**Routing Error
uninitialized constant Section**

if i delete the second line of routes.rb 
then i get 
**Routing Error
No route matches [POST] "/section/3/edit"**

not able to get why???

Answer (score 4):

1. Get rid of the first and second lines in your routes.rb. They're redundant. The `resources` will create these lines automatically.
2. The `resources :section` should be written as `resources :sections`. Notice that it's plural.
3. In your `index.html.erb`, you shouldn't mention `method:` at all. It's automatically set, and `:edit` as method doesn't exist. Method refers to put or get or delete, but you normally don't have to mention it.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need this lines in your `routes.rb`

```
post "section/new"
post "section/:id/edit"
```

Change the third line to:

```
resources :sections #plural
```

If you delete them, you can hit the edit view using

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_section_path(section.id), method: :edit %>
```

which will hit your app at `section/3/edit` with a `GET` request.

In your `edit.html.erb`, you can then have fields to capture edits and do a `PUT` to `/section/3`.

Note that RAILS uses HTTP verbs to define the CRUD operations. Ref [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions).

Answer (score 0):

Check your controller's file name because it should be plural. It is supposed to match the class name. So, you should rename `app/controllers/section_controller.rb` to `app/controllers/sections_controller.rb`.